# Volatility-Adjusted Relative Strength (and why my script does not work?)

Tags: pine-script, trading

Dear pine script experts!

I created a script in Pine to measure **volatility-adjusted relative strength** of an stock in comparison to the QQQ. I did the volatility adjustment using the **atr()**. The idea was that values < 0 indicate relative weakness and values > 0 indicate relative strength. Unfortunately, the outputs **do not fluctuate around zero** and I don't know why. Can anybody explain to me what I did wrong, or better yet, how I can solve the problem? I am desperate and by a newbie in programming in general (I just doing it for the result only :-))!

Thanks a lot for your help!

This is my **Intermediate result**:

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Volatility-Adjusted RS", shorttitle="VA-RS", overlay=false, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)

//Input
length = input.int(title="Length", defval=20, minval=1)
benchmark = input.symbol("NASDAQ:QQQ", title="Benchmark")

//Functions
atr_rma_function(security, length) =>
_high = request.security(security, timeframe.period, high)
_low = request.security(security, timeframe.period, low)
_close = request.security(security, timeframe.period, close)
trueRange = math.max(math.abs(_high - _close[1]), math.abs(_close[1]-_low))
ta.rma(trueRange, length)

//Calcs
benchMarkATR = atr_rma_function(benchmark, length)
benchMarkChange = math.abs(ta.change(request.security(benchmark, timeframe.period, close), length))

symbolATR = ta.atr(length)
symbolChange = math.abs(ta.change(close, length))

rs = (symbolATR/symbolChange) / (benchMarkATR/benchMarkChange) - 1
plot(rs)
hline(0)`
```

Comment: Could you please explain me why you expect the output to fluctuate around zero?

Comment: rs = (symbolATR/symbolChange) / (benchMarkATR/benchMarkChange) - 1

This should be because of the formula, or, put differently, because the right hand side changes are usually close to their respective ATRs.

Comment: Did you try to plot all those four variables (`symbolATR`, `symbolChange`, `benchMarkATR`, `benchMarkChange`) and see why you are getting the result you are getting?

Comment: I haven't even thought of that idea yet! I will do, then report back. Thanks

Comment: I have now plotted the functions as suggested. It turned out that the problem lies in the calculations of symbolChange and benchMarkChange. These are not calculated correctly. The output values for one day are by far too high. Do you have an idea what this could be?

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert of Pine, but can you try different approach, which is much simpler?
The definition is:
(Symbol*benchmark(ATR))/(Benchmark*Symbol(ATR))
No need for the change
Then you subtract that from the result of the prior 5th day
(Symbol*benchmark(ATR))/(Benchmark*Symbol(ATR))-(Symbol(5)*benchmark(ATR)(5))/(Benchmark(5)*Symbol(ATR)(5))
As long as the subtraction is greater than 0, overlay your chart with color.
It will insure you that the slope is positive, and when you receive a stack of color, you will know that there is strength.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).